# Java class that models a book

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, arraylist

Before asking the question I have to say that this is homework and I am only looking for ideas on how to implement a class that models a book.

A book has a title and many chapters, each chapter has a title and multiple subchapters. Every subchapter has a title and a list of paragraphs. Every paragraph can have a number and a text. I am looking to implement in OOP the following functionalities: add/remove: chapters, subchapters and paragraphs and display the book.
I am having some troubles finding the right structure for the class.

This is how I'm thinking of implementing it but it seems kind of redundant and complicated. Are there simpler and more correct ways to do it?

```
public class Element<T> {
        int nr;
        String Title;
        ArrayList<T> x = new ArrayList<T>();

        Element() {
            nr = 0;
            Title = "";
        }

        public void removeFromElement(int index) {
            if (index <= 0 && index > x.size())
                System.out.println("The chapter doesn't exist");
            else {
                x.remove(index);
                System.out.println("Succesful deletion");
            }
        }

        public void addToElement(T elem) {
            x.add(elem);
        }
    }

    public class Paragraph {
    int nr;
    String text;
    }

    public class Subchapter extends Element<Paragraph> {
    }

    public class Chapter extends Element<Subchapter> {
    }

    public class Book extends Element<Chapter> {
    }
```

Comment: This might work better on code review, although I'm thinking it's specific enough to still be on topic here too

Comment: what will be the value of `nr` in the case of `Book`?

Comment: Well, Book shouldn't have a number which is one of my problems.

Answer (score 5):

Your first approach is pretty good but does not take into account the possibility of evolution.

What would happen if we asked you to add the possibility for paragraphs to have 0-n quotes (or anything else) ?
What would happen if we asked you to add, in your book, a type of chapter which can't have subchapters ?

This will need huge changes. You should take a look at [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Following this pattern, you'll be way more flexible as far as evolutions are concerned.

When you think OOP, you must always keep in mind that interfaces can have a huge role in the way you'll design your code.
Many of theses problems have been already resolved and have a conventionnal solution (design patterns). You should take the time to learn the most common of them. It will definitly change your coding approach.

("Design pattern head first" would be a good book to read).

More over, one of the most important feature of OOP is the encapsulation.
This provide a very powerful way to control class' attributes' accessibility.
You MUST use it. Start by adding `private` or `protected` modifiers on your class' attributes and create the getters/setters needed to access/modify these attributes.

Another thing to take in note:
You should not use the `System.out.println()` method to logg your code. Use a log API (log4j for instance) and exceptions.

```
    public void removeFromElement(int index) throws ChapterNotFoundException{
        if (index <= 0 && index > x.size()){
            throw new ChapterNotFoundException(String.format("Chapter %s does not exist", index));
        }

        x.remove(index);
        logger.info(String.format("Chapter %s has been removed", index));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually not correct design. (but I like how you think about minimalize code writing)

The Book is not extended by chapter or "chapter elements". The book contains chapters and it also can contain/do something else.

Therefore the correct design is the simpliest one

```
public class Book{
    private String title;
    private List<Chapter> chapters;
}
//other classes would look similar
```

This approach is much more stable and it allows easy modification (or even replacement) in future.

This "phenomen" has also name, it is [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: So a design that doesn't use inheritance and just completely follows the description of the book is better?

Comment: This answer is wrong; `Book` doesn't extend `Chapter`. It extends a container which can only contain `Chapter`.

Comment: @J.Doe - in this case, the composition over inheritance has much more sense.

Comment: @AaronDigulla - yes, thats why I wrote: `...or "chapter elements"`

Comment: @J. Doe What you have is not necessarily wrong but this answer does make more sense. If you think in terms of "is-a" and "has-a" relationships it becomes clearer. Inheritance: Book `is-a` (i.e. extends) Chapter vs  Composition: Book `has-a` (i.e. contains) Chapter.

Comment: @Ciara Isn't it the same thing though? A book has chapter or a book is a list of chapters seem similar.

Comment: @libik: `Element` is a bad name; `Container` or `BookPart` would be better.  But if you want to avoid duplicating a lot of code, you need a common base class for all the containers and in this case, you can't use composition. What he actually need would be mix-ins but Java doesn't have them.

Comment: @J. Doe They are similar, especially in this case but there is a difference between "is a list of chapters" and "is a chapter" - think about it. The first one, "is a list of chapters" is essentially saying "contains chapters" which is a `has-a` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Your overall model actually makes a fair amount of sense. You've identified the repeated code and separated it out into a class. Your use of generics helps keep that clean. Whether it's worth explicitly separating out layers of the tree (for that's what this essentially is) as Subchapters, Chapters, etc depends on your exact requirements.

It might be simpler just to define tree nodes and leaves, but if you do need different behavior at each layer and don't need flexibility to add or remove more layers then this is fine. Consider for example if you will ever have an omnibus with Omnibus->Book->Chapter->Subchapter->Paragraph, or a book with Book->Chapter->Section->Subchapter->Paragraph. Could your model support those? If not does it need to?

Some of the naming could be clearer (for example nr as number) or doesn't follow style conventions (Title should be title).

The main mistake I'd say would be to store the number inside the object at all. That is fragile as it means you constantly have to update it as things are added, removed, etc.

You can always find out the number by just looking at the position in the parent. Essentially you are duplicating that information.

As Grégory pointed out in the comments all variables should be private and accessed via getters and setters.

Comment: He should as well add the access modifiers to protected/private and create the getters/setters.

Comment: Yes, this is more of an initial sketch, I'll add setters and getters if necessary. One thing that confuses me is that it seems like the subclasses don't have to implement any methods.

Comment: If they all have the same behavior then this is correct...but also suggests that perhaps you don't need them, see my 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is good. There are a few bugs in the code; I suggest to write a few unit tests to find them (hint: Try to delete pages).

I've written software to handle books in several languages (Java, Python, Groovy) and found that it's harder than it looks. The problem is that all elements (book, chapter, sub-chapter, paragraph) have many common features but subtle differences. Most of them are containers for specific types of other elements (so a book is made of chapter but not paragraphs). Only a paragraph isn't a container. All of them have a text (title or text of the paragraph) but the semantics of the text is different. Also, titles for sub-chapters don't make sense, or do they?

That makes it so hard to come up with a good API to handle all the corner cases without too much duplicated code, especially in a language like Java where you don't have [mixins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).